# A bug for char array in C

Tags: c

I want to print the following html to the console in C.However, there is a bug in my code which made me really confused, and I have no clue how could that happen? The bug is it print the last char array again.

Sample output:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <p>Hey There!</p>
        <p>You can search for things on the internet at:
            <ul>
            <li> <a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a></li>
            <li> <a href="http://www.bing.com">Bing</a></li>
            </ul>
        </p>
    </body>
    </html>

My output:
<html>
    <body>
        <p>Hey There!</p>
        <p>You can search for things on the internet at:
            <ul>
            <li> <a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a></li>
            following line is incorrect. It prints the above line again.
            <li> <a href="http://www.bing.com" href="http://www.google.com">Bing</a></li> 
            </ul>
        </p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
void open_tag(char tag[], char attribute[]){
char str1[100];
char str2[100];
char str3[100];
//The bug happens here.The attribute[] is incorrect.
strcpy (str1,tag);
strncat (str1, attribute, 100);
strcpy (str2,"<");
strcpy (str3,">");
strncat (str2, str1, 100);
strncat (str2, str3, 50);
printf ("%s",str2);
}
void close_tag(char tag[]){
char str1[20];
char str2[20];
char str3[20];
strcpy (str1,tag);
strcpy (str2,"</");
strcpy (str3,">");
strncat (str2, str1, 6);
strncat (str2, str3, 6);
printf ("%s",str2);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
open_tag("html", "");
printf("\n");
open_tag("body", "");
printf("\n");
open_tag("p", "");
printf("Hey There!");
close_tag("p");
printf("\n");
open_tag("p", "");
printf("You can search for things on the internet at:");
printf("\n");
open_tag("ul", "");
printf("\n");
open_tag("li", "");
char arr2[] = {' ','h','r','e','f','=','\"','h','t','t','p',':','/','/','w','w','w','.','g','o','o','g','l','e','.','c','o','m','\"'};
open_tag("a", arr2);
printf("Google");
close_tag("a");
close_tag("li");
printf("\n");
open_tag("li", "");
char arr1[] = {' ','h','r','e','f','=','\"','h','t','t','p',':','/','/','w','w','w','.','b','i','n','g','.','c','o','m',' ','\"'};  
open_tag("a", arr1);
printf("Bing");
close_tag("a");
close_tag("li");
printf("\n");
close_tag("ul");
printf("\n");
close_tag("p");
printf("\n");
close_tag("body");
printf("\n");
close_tag("html");
printf("\n");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: you should get rid of 95% of that code. after that you might see whats going on. example: `void open_tag(const char* tag, const char* attr) { printf("<%s", tag); if (attr && strlen(attr)) { printf(" %s", attr); } printf(">"); }` is enough.

Comment: Awful code.  `char arr1[] = {' ','h',` why not `char *arr1 = " href\=…` ?

Answer (score 2):

When you created and passed `attribute`, it is not null terminated. And then you forced it to copy 100 chars (using `strcat`), and then you appended characters at the end of it (`<` and `>`)

I suggest you put a terminator character on your `arr1` and `arr2` strings (by adding a `'\0'` character) before passing them.

Then don't use `strncat(..., 100)`, just use the plain `strcat()`.

Comment: Following the comment by Eddy_Em above, if you use a " http://" string, the compiler would nicely put the null termination in for you.

Comment: and the whole bunch of string-operations are not even needed ...

Comment: I can enumerate several more problems with the code (large allocation of variables on stack, unsafe string ops, code too long, too many function calls, better way to do the declaration as eddy_em noted above). 

Just pointed out the probable main cause of his repeated text problem -- garbage value in memory was copied unintentionally because of the non-terminated string.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
void open_tag(char tag[], char attribute[]){
    char str1[100];
    char str2[100];
    char str3[100];
    //The bug happens here.The attribute[] is incorrect.
    strcpy (str1,tag);
    strncat (str1, attribute, 100);
    strcpy (str2,"<");
    strcpy (str3,">");
    strncat (str2, str1, 100);
    strncat (str2, str3, 50);
    printf ("%s",str2);
}
```

Has got to be one of the most convoluted ways I've ever seen of writing this:

```
void open_tag(char const *tag, char const *attribute)
{
    printf("<%s %s>", tag, attribute);
}
```

Note that the replacement doesn't place arbitrary limits on the length of the tag or the attribute, so it is also more reliable (as well as a lot more easily readable).

The `close_tag()` function is similarly grotesque — it can be reduced to:

```
void close_tag(char const *tag)
{
    printf("</%s>", tag);
}
```

Of course, this assumes that you pass null terminated strings to the functions; if you don't do that, you're on a hiding to nothing.  So, your code:

```
char arr2[] = {' ','h','r','e','f','=','\"','h','t','t','p',':','/','/','w','w','w','.','g','o','o','g','l','e','.','c','o','m','\"'};
open_tag("a", arr2);
```

should become something more succinct, such as:

```
open_tag("a", "href=\"http://www.google.com\"");
```

The constness of the literal strings makes the `char const *tag` arguments desirable since they are not being modified.

Answer (score 0):

Cleaned up your code,

```
void open_tag(char* tag, char* attribute){

printf("<%s%s>",tag,attribute);

}

void close_tag(char* tag){

printf("</%s>",tag);    

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
char arr1[] = {' ','h','r','e','f','=','\"','h','t','t','p',':','/','/','w','w','w','.','b','i','n','g','.','c','o','m',' ','\"','\0'};  
char arr2[] = {' ','h','r','e','f','=','\"','h','t','t','p',':','/','/','w','w','w','.','g','o','o','g','l','e','.','c','o','m','\"','\0'};

open_tag("html", "");
printf("\n\t");

open_tag("body", "");
printf("\n\t\t");

open_tag("p", "");
printf("Hey There!");
close_tag("p");
printf("\n\t\t");

open_tag("p", "");
printf("You can search for things on the internet at:\n\t\t\t");
open_tag("ul", "");
printf("\n\t\t\t\t");
open_tag("li", "");

open_tag("a", arr2);
printf("Google");
close_tag("a");
close_tag("li");
printf("\n\t\t\t\t");
open_tag("li", "");
open_tag("a", arr1);
printf("Bing");
close_tag("a");
close_tag("li");
printf("\n\t\t\t");
close_tag("ul");
printf("\n\t\t");
close_tag("p");
printf("\n\t");
close_tag("body");
printf("\n");
close_tag("html");
printf("\n");

return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <p>Hey There!</p>
        <p>You can search for things on the internet at:
            <ul>
                <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.bing.com ">Bing</a></li>
            </ul>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Problems with your code : 
 1. Indentation
 2. Null Character in the Array
 3. Unnecessary Code

Although i cleaned up your code, you do realize that this way of coding is not really required.